# Storing an offline copy of the database

Tags: ios, database, swift, amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS Mobile Hub as a backend for my swift app.
The app uses table views which load data from DynamoDB, but I also need to have an offline copy of the Database inside the app so that it can still function offline but when it connects to the internet it should get the newest copy of the online Database. What is the best solution for this to work?

Comment: Why don't you use Core Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways.

If data is no so big just store json string to NSUserDefaults. Every time you load new data update userdetaults that way you can sync with new data.

If data is big than use coredata.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably settle in for Core Data although it's not the most developer friendly system ;P